# clang compiler flags for binary distribution (generic CPU)

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

I'm compiling a cross-platform C/C++ CLI app for OSX using `cmake` and `clang` (700.1.81) on OSX 10.11 on a ~1 y.o. RMBP. I'm using CPack to package my application up as a drag-n-drop `.dmg` installer.

When I test the binary on older machines (~ 4 .y.o) I'm regularly getting a `SIGILL` illegal instruction fault (even on the same OSX version).  What are the magic compiler invocations I should be using to build for a "generic" CPU? `llc` for instance supports a `-mpcu=generic` flag, but clang doesn't recognise that flag, and the clang `man` page suggests `-march=cpu`, but if I try `-march=generic` I get an `error: unknown target CPU 'generic'` error.

I'm already specifying older OSX versions through `-mmacosx-version-min`, that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Do I have to specify a generic CPU through a target triple? What are the options there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a generic architecture, try `-march=x86-64`. That should prevent, for example, Haswell-specific instructions from being generated.

Comment: I've used `-march=x86-64` to generate something generic on an i7, but when I tried to execute in a Pentium G (both 64bit) I got tons of Illegal instructions. Will try `-mtune=generic` rather